# Syncronize time between 4 pc linux with millisecond precision (for a fancy purpose)

Tags: bash, time, synchronization

I disposed four laptops in a grid configuration using some tripods and I want to reproduce one corner of a video for each laptop, so to get a video split over the four screens.
The laptops are identical and each of them is running Linux Mint.

Every laptop has the video locally and with `avplay` I was able to reproduce the four rectangles of the video that I need.

I wrote a script which gets the local time `t` (in milliseconds) of one of the four computers, then create 4 bash scripts which role is to enter in an infinite loop which will break only when the current time is greater than `t + 5` seconds, and then the scripts are then copied with `scp` to each laptop and run.

Everything works but the video are not perfectly syncronize.
I think that this is due to the fact that the local time of the four pcs are not syncronized to the millisecond.

My question: *how can I sync them?*

Comment: you will need to use ntp. google "setup ntp server'.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr working like a charm

Comment: or you will need to use [ptp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_Time_Protocol).